# Check and Retry uploading file when internet down

Tags: c#

I have to upload some list of files to another service which works fine as of now. But during upload if the internet connection failed then I need to start monitoring the internet connection for some timeout period and if the connection is back then need to send upload request. if the connection doesn't come before timeout then log the failure message.

```
try {
    var uploadResponse = await service.UploadFile(filePath, id);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    if(CheckInternetTillTimeout()) {  //check internet till timeout mentioned (eg. 5000ms)
       //retry uploading
    }
    else {
    Console.log("Internet not available");
    }
}
```

**CheckInternetTillTimeout** should check for internet connection for some time period if connection available then return true, else if connection not available then return false after mentioned timeout.

Comment: Are you OK with learning a 3rd Party Lib like Polly or do you want / need to do it all by yourself? Are you allowed to switch to async/Task (easier to do non-spin-wait-timeouts)?

Comment: yes I want to do myself and ok to use async/Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply retrying the upload after a delay?

[Polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/) is a very popular library to do exactly that.

Comment: I specifically need to check for internet down and reupload when internet is back

Comment: How would you detect that Internet is up/down? - If you can answer that question, you can make a Polly Policy that will reflect that. Including your timeout requirements.

Comment: when flow hit the catch block will check the internet connectivity

Comment: when it is disconnected you could poll for a connection every x seconds. There is no automated flag for the internet reconnecting. You could then time out after a certain number of time has elapsed since the first attempt.

Comment: The catch block is the right place but like what @Fildor says, how would you detect that the internet is down? You could try to connect to some known endpoint on the internet like google.com for example but that only checks if google.com is online (what if google is offline and your upload endpoint is up?). A better approach is to check if your upload endpoint is online by just retrying the upload.